# CodeIgniter - Unable to Extract Field From Record

Tags: codeigniter

The code below works, allowing me to retrieve all fields for a single record.  One of the fields I use from this record is 'name' but to access it on the view page, I must place two lines of code to extract the 'name' field from the record returned. I want to be able to extract the 'name' field in the controller and pass to view. I'm sure there is a simply solution since the data is already successfully retrieved.

MODEL - Performs a select all and returns a single record

```
// Select a record (all columns) from 'proposal_info' table per prop ID
public function get_propinfo($propid) {
  // Build query
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('proposal_info P'); 
  $this->db->join('status', 'P.status = status.id');
  $this->db->join('regions', 'P.region = regions.id');
  $this->db->join('usa_states', 'P.state_id = usa_states.id');
  $this->db->join('type', 'P.type = type.id');
  $this->db->where('P.id', $propid);
  return $this->db->get();
}
```

CONTROLLER - The $data['propinfo'] = $this->Propinfo_model->get_propinfo($_SESSION['session_propid']); line is where I retrieve the record from the query in the model.  The 'name' field is contained within the $data['propinfo'] but how can I retrieve it here in the controller?  Seems like it would

```
public function summary() {
  $this->load->model('Propinfo_model');
  $data['page'] = "Project Summary";
  $data['allprops'] = $this->Propinfo_model->get_allprops($_SESSION['userid_db']); // required for LH nav proj list 
  $data['propinfo'] = $this->Propinfo_model->get_propinfo($_SESSION['session_propid']); // query for proposal info
  $data['announcements'] = $this->Propinfo_model->get_announcements($_SESSION['session_propid']); // query for announcements
  $this->load->view('templates/bp_header_view', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/bp_nav_view', $data); 
  $this->load->view('summary_view', $data); // page content 
  $this->load->view('templates/bp_footer_view', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/bp_endjs_view', $data);
}
```

VIEW - Unfortunately, this is the only way I know how to get the 'name' field.  This wks, but I want to do this at the controller, not the view.

```
// Want to remove this code from the view and have 'name' passed from controller
$row = $propinfo->row_array();
$proposal_name = $row['name'];
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only want the name from the database in your views used in your summary method?

Comment: CI db methods are chainable, so can you use `$this->db->query()->row_array()` in your model and just return the array to `$data['propinfo']` in the controller? I honestly don't know because I don't use CI's ORM but it seems like you could do some variation of that in the model if you're only returning one row.

Comment: TimB - I needed all fields but I wanted to see how to display a single field on view page using 'name' as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, have the model return the row_array by changing the last line of `get_propinfo($propid)` to this

```
return $this->db->get()->row_array();
```

Then in the view you get "name" with

```
echo $propinfo['name'];
```

If you want to get "name" in the controller then

```
$name = $data['propinfo']['name'];
```

Unrelated to your question but I cannot help myself. Your view loading could be a bit cleaner if you did this.

```
$this->load
     ->view('templates/bp_header_view', $data)
     ->view('templates/bp_nav_view')
     ->view('summary_view')
     ->view('templates/bp_footer_view')
     ->view('templates/bp_endjs_view');
```

Method chaining will execute a bit quicker and it is way less typing.

There is no need to pass `$data` on each view load. Once data is sent to a `load->view` it is cached and will be visible to subsequent `load->view` calls. If you keep passing it the you keep running a bunch of code overwriting the cache with the same values it already has. You only need to pass some data if you're actually adding or changing data that a view needs.

And as @ourmandave points out, method chaining works for `db` methods too. Try this in the model.

```
return $this->db
   ->join('status', 'P.status = status.id')
   ->join('regions', 'P.region = regions.id')
   ->join('usa_states', 'P.state_id = usa_states.id')
   ->join('type', 'P.type = type.id')
   ->where('P.id', $propid)
   ->get('proposal_info P') 
   ->row_array();
```

Notice the removal of of a `select('*')` and `from('proposal_info P')`. The table name has been moved to the `get()`call.

When using a`db->get('optional table name')` without a `select()` call, the query statement produced will have a `SELECT *`clause.

Yea, less typing is your friend.

Comment: Thx Dave!  This is the solution I needed.  Thx for the method chaining best practice as well!